# Does an active low pin need a pull up resistor?

Tags: pullup, nrf24l01

I am interfacing a PIC24 microcontroller with [this nRF24L01 2.4GHz transceiver](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00E594ZX0). The transceiver has an active low interrupt pin that is toggled on transmit and a few other instances. Does this pin need to be pulled up or not? I imagine that it works similar to a normally high switch like the diagram below, in which case I think it should be pulled up.

[image: pullup resistor]

Comment: No, active-low just means that whatever it is signaling about has a negative logic. You need the pull-up only if you have an open-drain output on that pin.

Comment: Pull-ups and pull-downs are to keep a pin in a known state. Floating inputs on a MCU are strongly discouraged as they can cause undesired operation, and the oscillations can heat up your chip and cause damage. In the case of your schematic above, yes--a pull-up resistor is definitely recommended. Otherwise the pin will be left floating (neither high nor low) and if it fluctuates low it will read it like the button is closed when it's not. The pull-up is a very good idea

Comment: @derstrom8 The schematic is the OP's understanding of the module, which I believe is a not correct understanding...

Comment: Whether you need a pull-up for the device you mentioned or not, you'll need to look at the datasheet. I have not

Comment: Sorry, see my last comment. The OP definitely needs to read the datasheet, which shoudl tell him whether or not one is needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether a signal needs a pull-up resistor depends on how it is driven.

If the driving logic is open-drain or open-collector or a mechanical switch pulling down like in your example schematic, then a pull-up is required to ensure a valid high logic level is produced when the line is not driven.

If the driving logic has totem-pole drivers, then no pull-up is required (because the output is capable of driving the high level itself).

Open drain drivers are often used with active low signals, because it allows multiple drivers to be connected together, producing an active-low "wired-OR" logic. In this configuration, any one of several drivers can produce a low value on the line, and only if all the drivers release the line is a high value produced (by the pull-up). This configuration is common for things like reset and interrupt signals.

Comment: "If the driving logic has totem-pole drivers, then no pull-up is required (because the output is capable of driving the high level itself).".May I know during power on what is the state of the totem pole outputs.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/SMD/nRF24L01Pluss_Preliminary_Product_Specification_v1_0.pdf) for the nRF24L01+ the pin is driven high when reset in the status register and driven low for an interrupt.

[image]

I included a screenshot of the datasheet because they *disabled* copying text from it. *So annoying*.